# ¿De dónde viene y hasta cuándo se usó «saber de coro»?

Tags: modismos, expresiones

Comenzando a leer los preliminares del Quijote me encuentro con que se emplea la expresión «saber de coro» (que significa "saber de memoria"). Más allá de que una nota al pie lo aclara, el contexto lo dejaba en claro y además la expresión parece un calco fonético del portugués «*(saber) de cor*», que significa precisamente eso (y el verbo portugués *decorar* significa "memorizar" además de "ornamentar"). Lo achaqué a la antigüedad del texto. Sin embargo buscando rápidamente encuentro que José Martí utiliza esta misma expresión en una carta fechada en 1883. En un diccionario español de 1786 [la misma](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=rpVgQDEcD7kC&lpg=PA525&ots=LaN8KMupby&dq=%22saber%20de%20coro%22&pg=PA525#v=onepage&q=%22saber%20de%20coro%22&f=false) aparece también con su entrada propia.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cuándo dejó de ser usada esta expresión? ¿Era arcaizante ya a fines del siglo XIX? Y sobre todo, ¿cuál es su origen (etimológico, figurativo)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me ha resultado muy llamativo que, al igual que en inglés se dice "I know it by heart" para "me lo sé de memoria", haciendo referencia al corazón, esta expresión tenga su origen en el mismo órgano.

Cito el *Diccionario de Autoridades*:

> CORO. Se toma tambien por memória. Usase regularmente de esta voz con las phrases Saber, decir, ò tomar de coro. [...] Vemos que la memória del celébro se halla en el corazón virtualmente, de donde tuvo origen esta habla Castellana, con que decimos *tomar de coro*, por decir tomar de corde, ò de corazón.

Se ve que esta creencia de que la memoria se hallaba en el corazón influyó en la creación de las expresiones portuguesa, inglesa y española (al menos). Veo conforme voy examinando el NTLLE que la expresión se mantuvo en el diccionario bastante tiempo. De hecho, en la edición de 1899 del DLE se registra la expresión "Coro (De)" en una entrada aparte a la habitual de "Coro" por tener una etimología diferente:

> **Coro (De).** (Del lat. *cor*, ánimo.) m. adv. De memoria. Ú. regularmente con los verbos *decir*, *saber* ó *tomar*.

No veo que la expresión se marcara en ningún momento como "en desuso", no al menos hasta muy recientemente: en la edición de 1992 del DLE se mantiene la entrada "Coro (de)" pero ya con la marca "poco usada". Y de hecho, [sigue en el diccionario a día de hoy](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AuszJke), con la misma marca.

Como curiosidad, las palabras españolas *recordar* y *acordarse* también contienen esa raíz *cor*. Según Corominas:

> RECORDAR 'tener recuerdo de algo', 1220-50. Del latín RECORDARI íd. (derivado de COR 'corazón'). De este verbo derivó además el castellano su *acordarse* 'tener memoria de algo', 1240, ajeno a las demás lenguas romances.

Comment: Acabo de caer en la cuenta de que *recordar* también viene (supuestamente) de *cordis* "corazón".